# замена слеша на %2f в URL

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить с апишки данные. Адрес [https://rogaikopita.ru/api/product/{name}/size](https://rogaikopita.ru/api/product/%7Bname%7D/size). Что делать если

```
const name = 'bad/poor name';
```

обработка через encodeURIComponent и замена слеша на %2f не помогает - переходим по адресу будто и нет замены. Понятно, что если бы был доступ к бэкенду можно было бы кучу всего сделать от кодировки в Base64 с последующей расшифровкой, до установки директивы AllowEncodedSlashes в NoDecode в настройках сервера.

А есть какие-то варианты пробросить это туда не имея доступа к серверу?

Comment: а чем именно делается запрос ? (лучше привести кусок кода от кодирования до отправки запроса) вообще %2f должен помогать, если принимающий api сам готов к такому (видел api, в которых были ошибки в подобных ситуациях, пришлось писать разработчикам и долго ждать пока исправят)

Comment: JS из браузера `axios.get(\`https://rogaikopita.ru/api/product/${encodeURIComponent(name)}/size\`)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const name = 'bad/poor name'
const url = `https://rogaikopita.ru/api/product/${encodeURIComponent(name)}/size`
console.log(url)
```

Comment: Дак это понятно. У меня так и есть. Но по умолчанию на Apache сервере AllowEncodedSlashes установлено в off и ему наплевать на то, что у вас %2f вместо слеша, он эти символы так же считает слешем и как итог получаем переход по адресу https://rogaikopita.ru/api/product/bad/poor%20name/size

Comment: @АлександрРогонов А тогда ваш код совершенно не причем. Все правильно сделано. А вот апач надо настраивать по другому. без вариантов.